# Знаки вокруг значка копирайта

Tags: пунктуация, кавычки

«Мы красивый клип из вашего материала сделаем. Вам понравится, обещаю! Вам приятно будет. И людям приятно будет! А если людям приятно будет, «слушай, я тебя так довезу, что и тебе приятно будет» ©»!

Это прямая речь, закавыченная. Но кончается она цитатой...

Если я сменю рисунок кавычек у цитаты, я помогу копирайту?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Кавычки другого типа помогли бы, да само употребление знака неверно: он должен сопровождаться ссылкой на правообладателя и годовой датой (в тексте полную такую ссылку логично было бы поместить в скобки). Без этого выглядит так, будто помеченное безвременно принадлежит автору внутренней цитаты (сценаристу), - это так?

Comment: Нет. Процитирована какая-то пошлая песенка или анекдот, и автора никому знать не надо. Смысл - не припишите пошлятину рассказчику!

Comment: Я предполагаю, что эта цитата - из "Мимино", возможно, намеренно искажённая.

Comment: Оч хор! А с копирайтом-то что? Про него вопрос-то!

Comment: "Ссылка на автора лучше ссылки на Колыму" © (это означает, что копирайт мой, год точно не помню - раз мой, не приставайте с подробностями), а здесь по науке надо: «... "... "(© Мосфильм, 1977)». Ещё один вопрос возникает: как такой текст вслух прочитать?

Comment: Саш, это - про дельфинов - одна из лучших историй, захватывающая! Памяти Дмитрия Марьянова посвящается... Куда прислать текст (пока ещё не согласованный с автором в смысле правки?